# I'd like someone to help me understand a few lines of code. Can someone help me explain them? Thanks

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an algorithm on Codesignal.

For `s = "abacabad"`, the output should be
`firstNotRepeatingCharacter(a) = 'c'`.

There are 2 non-repeating characters in the string: 'c' and 'd'. Return c since it appears in the string first.

For `s = "abacabaabacaba"`, the output should be
`firstNotRepeatingCharacter(s) = '_'`.

There are no characters in this string that do not repeat.

Code below:

```
function firstNotRepeatingCharacter(a) {
  let b = {};
  let len = a.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let tmp = a.charAt(i);
    if (b[tmp]) {
      b[tmp] += 1; //explain here
    }
    else {
      b[tmp] = 1;
    }
  }

  for (var prop in b) {
    if (b[prop] == 1) { //explain here
      return prop;
    }
  }
  return '_';
}
```

Comment: The first "explain here" is clearly incrementing a previous value; and the second "explain here" is looking for the first entry that is equal to 1 (if there is one). Ergo, the only question is why does `b[tmp]` as an assignment work? Once that is clear, then the rest is straight forward.

Comment: The person asking the question is likely a novice, so the rest is *not* straightforward. Actually, the way this algorithm works depends on a rather subtle detail, that the `for` loop iterates over the object's keys in insertion order. That happens to be true in Javascript, but relying on it means the algorithm is hardly straightforward, even if you aren't a novice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the above `b` is an object whose keys are different letters of the string and the values of those keys are count of respective lettter in the string.

```
key => letter
value => Count of that letter
```

`tmp` will be character through you are iterating. 
`if (b[tmp])` checks whether the letter is already added to the object.

- If its already there so increase the count.
- Otherwise set it to one.

In the second loop `if (b[prop] == 1)` checks whether the count of certain letter is `1`. means that it only occurred once in the string so return the letter.